# Property '_measure' doesn't exist, js engine: hermes error while using react drawer navigator with EXPO react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, navigation-drawer

Getting below error while integrating drawer navigator with EXPO react-native:

ERROR  ReferenceError: Property '_measure' doesn't exist, js engine: hermes

ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:

* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.

* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes

**package.json looks like this:**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@expo/webpack-config": "^19.0.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.8",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.3",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.13",
    "expo": "~49.0.8",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.3.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.22.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@types/react": "~18.0.14",
    "expo-router": "^2.0.5",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.9",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  },
```

**babel.config.js looks like this:**

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ["babel-preset-expo", 'module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
    plugins: [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from",
      "react-native-reanimated/plugin", 'expo-router/babel',
      require.resolve("expo-router/babel"),
      ["module:react-native-dotenv", {
        "envName": "APP_ENV",
        "moduleName": "@env",
        "path": ".env",
        "safe": false,
        "allowUndefined": true,
        "verbose": false
      }]
    ],
  };
};
```

**drawer navigator component looks like this:**

```
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import Settings from './settings';

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

export default function DrawerNavigator() {
    return (
        <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Settings">
            <Drawer.Screen name="Settings" component={Settings} />
            <Drawer.Screen name="Article" component={Settings} />
        </Drawer.Navigator>
    );
}
```

**app.tsx looks like this:**

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import DrawerNavigator from './screens/drawer';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <TabNavigator />
      <DrawerNavigator />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

I have tried changing varios version of "react-native-reanimated" but didn't work

Comment: Did you try resetting the Metro cache

Comment: Yes, I tried resettint the Metro cache as well but it didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

I just resolved the same problem for me. I have a react native application with `expo-router` and I have downloaded the `react-native-reanimated` library from expo (this libraby is the cause of the error).

What I have done to solve the problem for me is:

- Delete the `node_modules` folder
- Remove the `react-native-reanimated` dependency from `package.json` file
- Run `npm i`

After everything is downloaded:

- Run `npx expo install react-native-reanimated`
- Add `react-native-reanimated/plugin` as a plugin in `babel.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = function(api) {
   api.cache(true);
   return {
      presets: ["babel-preset-expo"],
      plugins: ["react-native-reanimated/plugin"],
   };
};
```

!!! Keep in mind that the reanimated plugin should be at the end of the array as pointed in the documentation as it needs to be the last loaded plugin !!!

Then you need to clear all cache because babel caches all plugins:

- Run `npx expo start --clear`

I hope this helps you as it did for me. You could read more here: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/reanimated